# Power BI: Overwrite date slicer for prior year calculations

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure in DAX for prior year numbers, which I normally wouldn't have a problem with, but I'm running into some trouble when there is also a date slicer involved.

My current formula looks something like this:

```
PY Amount = 
    CALCULATE(
         SUM(Facts[Amount]),
         SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Dates[Date])
    )
```

Usually, this is fine. However, the report consumer needs to apply a date filter, since certain months may still be pending. This gives me the result I want for the current year, but it's also returning blanks for the prior year:
[image]

I tried using the `ALL` function, but no luck. Any advice?

(I should also mention that our fiscal year runs from October-September.)